# Making a function wait a certain amount of time before it executes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, nstimer

I have a button which when clicked, I want it to wait 10 seconds before it does its thing like for example switching to a new view. How would I go about in doing this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10):

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

Read up on the NSObject documentation for a few other variants.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myFunction:) withObject:myObject afterDelay:10.0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then `timer:` should look like this:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
      //do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
double delayInSeconds = 10.0; // number of seconds to wait
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    /***********************
     * Your code goes here *
     ***********************/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `NSTimer`,

Check the below code as reference.

```
- (void) startTimer{

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithInterval:10.0f target:self selector:@selector(showElapsedTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

`showElapsedTime` will be called after delay, you provide.

```
-(void) showElapsedTime: (NSTimer *) timer {

    if(OnSomeCondition)
    {
      [timer invalidate];
    }

// Write your code here 
}
```

Call `StartTimer` from your **action method** of your `UIButton`, you will get 10 second wait.

```
-(void) myButtonAction:(id) sender
{
   [self StartTimer]; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do a

```
sleep(10)
```

to make the app pause for 10 seconds. Note: This is a real, real pause, so no UI interaction is possible at all. Pressing the Home button will work and move your app to the background, though.

Comment: Probably not the best way to do this. If you did want to disable user interaction during the pause, just use a timer like in my answer, and just do `userInteractionEnabled = NO;` on the current view. But don't forget to reenable interaction after.

Comment: If you sleep the main thread and the user pushes the Home or Sleep buttons, your app won't respond to notifications and the system will terminate it, giving no chance to save the user's work.